# onClick not responding

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

this is my first question on StackOverflox (and I'm quite nervous about it)
I spent my week-end trying to do some AJAx and I did not succeed...
I followed this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eJHHIcScqYA and tried to follow it for my code.
I have this in my view and javascript: (pardon my french!):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#delete_beerlist').on("click", function(){
    $.ajax({
      url: '/beer_lists/' + this.parentElement.id,
      type: 'DELETE',
      succes: function(r){

      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<h3> Pression </h3>

<% @draft_beers.each do |item| %>
  <tr id='<%= item.id%>'> 
    <td> <%= Beer.find(item.beer_id).name %> - </td> 
    <td> Prix pinte:  <%= item.pint_price %> - </td>
    <td> Prix demi: <%= item.half_pint_price %> - </td>
    <td> <%= link_to "modifier les prix", edit_beer_list_path(item.id) %> - </td> 
    <td id='delete_beerlist'>Supprimer</td> 
  </tr> </br>
<% end %>

<h3> Bouteille </h3>
<% @bottle_beers.each do |item| %>
  <tr id='<%=item.id%>'> 
    <td> <%= Beer.find(item.beer_id).name %> -</td>
    <td> Prix bouteille: <%= item.bottle_price %>  -</td>
    <td> <%= link_to "modifier le prix", edit_beer_list_path(item.id) %> </td> -
    <td id='delete_beerlist'>Supprimer</td> 
  </tr> </br>
<% end %>
```

And the onClick doesn't give anything in my console. I have the gem 'jquery-rails' and I require 'jquery3' in my application.js, it's quite driving me mad >.<
Thanks for the help!

Edit: this is my generated HTML code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Beerly</title>
    <meta name="csrf-param" content="authenticity_token" />
<meta name="csrf-token" content="B9vuLIENHSH2351ga9VW44ka6PFPLEP8Cu6zdMfgMZDZeuDKVWWrmafMTDAWdBmdRGfyLrpEStZ7xcUgOUjH5Q==" />
    

    <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/r-chrome.self-cc72d6b06fc2d60739fd45c645a0689aa61b37cf49950538dacaeb5a7ecc5d79.css?body=1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/r-firefox.self-89fb2eca5e6840a84fbfd889939e747e6b41b2b590bcd6c2ac44f8ae5c48cd3e.css?body=1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/bootstrap.min.self-43023147d9420f0da40facdf09ece46460a1ea2eee23a03ab10f3d16b895ea52.css?body=1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/apropos.self-e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855.css?body=1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/bars.self-e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855.css?body=1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/beer_lists.self-e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855.css?body=1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/beers.self-e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855.css?body=1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/contact.self-af976636f1970c397e9281424f2a0e5f37bf97cd6ab2013e5c0cb44f3588c8c7.css?body=1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/custom-bootstrap.self-7a5e46bedd72d2a3a75604d3c99e0355fdb7cb28935a7dac9c2d9bc73c8aca93.css?body=1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/home.self-eb5ab899aa47638786ef95d408c673b47fff2391e7850978006620a39c79c532.css?body=1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/hover.self-dd1c301d16e4556535c6986f12eaa121f5253bbbf59645fb836e2b0bcf2beb0f.css?body=1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/map.self-e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855.css?body=1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/mentionlegale.self-e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855.css?body=1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/resultpage.self-6795a6e6f5532b292242295b7172cd1a59b9bb2ad4e6f16d4d5790e1bb0e4b8f.css?body=1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/application.self-7dd66a9c9e781d6a4fbcc394eaae76758454669b87bd4cb570df5cdba9afb664.css?body=1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-B4dIYHKNBt8Bc12p+WXckhzcICo0wtJAoU8YZTY5qE0Id1GSseTk6S+L3BlXeVIU" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  </head>
   <header id="shd">
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light container pt-4 pb-4">
  <div class="navbar-brand"><a href="/"><img class="logo" alt="logo" src="/assets/logo-68dee4b2513dbe544670d3e6e11b3dee11c0c5f78567b0baf41e4e87d7a2d11e.svg" /></a></div>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">

    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="/">Accueil</a>        
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
         <a class="nav-link" href="contact">Contact</a> 
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
         <a class="nav-link" href="apropos">À propos</a> 
      </li>


      <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="/managers/bars/1/edit">Mon bar</a> 
      </li>       
      <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/managers/sign_out">Se déconnecter</a> 
      </li> 

      
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
<header>

 
   <body>
    <h2> Ma carte </h2>

<h3> Pression </h3>

  <tr id='3'> 
    <td> La Chouffe - </td> 
    <td> Prix pinte:  5.0 - </td>
    <td> Prix demi: 2.5 - </td>
    <td> <a href="/beer_lists/3/edit">modifier les prix</a> - </td> 
    <td class='delete_beerlist'>Supprimer</td> 
  </tr> </br>
  <tr id='5'> 
    <td> La Chouffe - </td> 
    <td> Prix pinte:  5.0 - </td>
    <td> Prix demi: 2.5 - </td>
    <td> <a href="/beer_lists/5/edit">modifier les prix</a> - </td> 
    <td class='delete_beerlist'>Supprimer</td> 
  </tr> </br>
  <tr id='7'> 
    <td> La Chouffe - </td> 
    <td> Prix pinte:  5.0 - </td>
    <td> Prix demi: 2.5 - </td>
    <td> <a href="/beer_lists/7/edit">modifier les prix</a> - </td> 
    <td class='delete_beerlist'>Supprimer</td> 
  </tr> </br>
  <tr id='13'> 
    <td> La Chouffe - </td> 
    <td> Prix pinte:  5.0 - </td>
    <td> Prix demi: 2.5 - </td>
    <td> <a href="/beer_lists/13/edit">modifier les prix</a> - </td> 
    <td class='delete_beerlist'>Supprimer</td> 
  </tr> </br>
  <tr id='15'> 
    <td> La Chouffe - </td> 
    <td> Prix pinte:  5.0 - </td>
    <td> Prix demi: 2.5 - </td>
    <td> <a href="/beer_lists/15/edit">modifier les prix</a> - </td> 
    <td class='delete_beerlist'>Supprimer</td> 
  </tr> </br>
  <tr id='19'> 
    <td> La Chouffe - </td> 
    <td> Prix pinte:  5.0 - </td>
    <td> Prix demi: 2.5 - </td>
    <td> <a href="/beer_lists/19/edit">modifier les prix</a> - </td> 
    <td class='delete_beerlist'>Supprimer</td> 
  </tr> </br>

<h3> Bouteille </h3>
  <tr id='2'> 
    <td> La Chouffe -</td>
    <td> Prix bouteille: 7.0  -</td>
    <td> <a href="/beer_lists/2/edit">modifier le prix</a> </td> -
    <td class='delete_beerlist'>Supprimer</td> 
  </tr> </br>
  <tr id='4'> 
    <td> La Chouffe -</td>
    <td> Prix bouteille: 7.0  -</td>
    <td> <a href="/beer_lists/4/edit">modifier le prix</a> </td> -
    <td class='delete_beerlist'>Supprimer</td> 
  </tr> </br>
  <tr id='6'> 
    <td> La Chouffe -</td>
    <td> Prix bouteille: 7.0  -</td>
    <td> <a href="/beer_lists/6/edit">modifier le prix</a> </td> -
    <td class='delete_beerlist'>Supprimer</td> 
  </tr> </br>
  <tr id='8'> 
    <td> La Chouffe -</td>
    <td> Prix bouteille: 7.0  -</td>
    <td> <a href="/beer_lists/8/edit">modifier le prix</a> </td> -
    <td class='delete_beerlist'>Supprimer</td> 
  </tr> </br>
  <tr id='10'> 
    <td> La Chouffe -</td>
    <td> Prix bouteille: 7.0  -</td>
    <td> <a href="/beer_lists/10/edit">modifier le prix</a> </td> -
    <td class='delete_beerlist'>Supprimer</td> 
  </tr> </br>
  <tr id='12'> 
    <td> La Chouffe -</td>
    <td> Prix bouteille: 7.0  -</td>
    <td> <a href="/beer_lists/12/edit">modifier le prix</a> </td> -
    <td class='delete_beerlist'>Supprimer</td> 
  </tr> </br>
  <tr id='14'> 
    <td> La Chouffe -</td>
    <td> Prix bouteille: 7.0  -</td>
    <td> <a href="/beer_lists/14/edit">modifier le prix</a> </td> -
    <td class='delete_beerlist'>Supprimer</td> 
  </tr> </br>
  <tr id='16'> 
    <td> La Chouffe -</td>
    <td> Prix bouteille: 7.0  -</td>
    <td> <a href="/beer_lists/16/edit">modifier le prix</a> </td> -
    <td class='delete_beerlist'>Supprimer</td> 
  </tr> </br>
  <tr id='18'> 
    <td> La Chouffe -</td>
    <td> Prix bouteille: 7.0  -</td>
    <td> <a href="/beer_lists/18/edit">modifier le prix</a> </td> -
    <td class='delete_beerlist'>Supprimer</td> 
  </tr> </br>
  <tr id='20'> 
    <td> La Chouffe -</td>
    <td> Prix bouteille: 7.0  -</td>
    <td> <a href="/beer_lists/20/edit">modifier le prix</a> </td> -
    <td class='delete_beerlist'>Supprimer</td> 
  </tr> </br>
 

<h1>Cherche ta bière </h1>

<form action="/managers/beer_lists" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="get"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" />
  <input type="text" name="term" id="term" />
  <input type="submit" value="Search" data-disable-with="Search" />
</form></br>
</br>



    <!-- Footer -->
<footer class="page-footer font-small sticky-bottom pt-5 pb-5 mt-6">

  <div class="container">

    <!-- Footer Links -->
    <div class="container-fluid text-center text-md-left">

      <!-- Grid row -->
      <div class="row">

        <!-- Grid column -->
        <div class="col-md-6 mt-md-0 mt-3 text-dark">

          <!-- Content -->
          
          <div class="navbar-brand"><a href="/"><img class="logo-footer" alt="logo" src="/assets/logo-68dee4b2513dbe544670d3e6e11b3dee11c0c5f78567b0baf41e4e87d7a2d11e.svg" /></a></div>

        </div>
        <!-- Grid column -->

        <hr class="clearfix w-100 d-md-none pb-3">

        <!-- Grid column -->
        <div class="col-md-3 mb-md-0 mb-3">

            <!-- Links -->
            <h5 class="text-uppercase text-dark">Links</h5>

            <ul class="list-unstyled text-dark">
              <li>
                <a href="#!" class="nav-item">Link 1</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#!" class="nav-item">Link 2</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#!" class="nav-item">Link 3</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#!" class="nav-item">Link 4</a>
              </li>
            </ul>

          </div>
          <!-- Grid column -->

          <!-- Grid column -->
          <div class="col-md-3 mb-md-0 mb-3 text-dark">

            <!-- Links -->
            <h5 class="text-uppercase">Links</h5>

            <ul class="list-unstyled">
              <li>
                  <a class="nav-item" href="/">Accueil</a>  
              </li>
              <li>
                <a class="nav-item" href="contact">Contact</a> 
              </li>
              <li>
                  <a class="nav-item" href="apropos">À propos</a> 
              </li>
              <li>
                <a class="nav-item" href="mentions-legales">Mentions Légales</a> 
              </li>
            </ul>

          </div>
          <!-- Grid column -->

      </div>
      <!-- Grid row -->

    </div>
    <!-- Footer Links -->

  
    <!-- Copyright -->
  </div>
  </footer> 
    <script src="/assets/popper.min.self-71f355c150b0a532df467fea2bf02ec471bcfe1c86463c9a71a32f5fe94c3007.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap.min.self-a8e68c223de43929594bd637b85532a803195ce936a435f51c444e697dac8d1f.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/rails-ujs.self-d109d8c5c0194c8ad60b8838b2661c5596b5c955987f7cd4045eb2fb90ca5343.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/activestorage.self-1ed4604ac2170045f1ffca4edb81a75246661555e4f9cf682bb8a21825e32e1c.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery3.self-5af507e253c37e9c9dcf65064fc3f93795e6e28012780579975a4d709f4074ad.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/beer_lists.self-eac9e7c016b6d45c447b1b13a02c83b6657ec16316db179d1c59593c227112b3.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/action_cable.self-69fddfcddf4fdef9828648f9330d6ce108b93b82b0b8d3affffc59a114853451.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/cable.self-8484513823f404ed0c0f039f75243bfdede7af7919dda65f2e66391252443ce9.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/application.self-6a7f81c89608537f1c0b5e6e1a1cad14caec515ae09b88e0406efa9bcbfd4752.js?body=1"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `delete_beerlist` should be a class, not an id as ids should be unique

Comment: Thanks! I tried several things, it was initially a class, I just changed it back, didn't change my problem.

Comment: Hi, this code does not appear to output anything to the console. What are you expecting to be in the console?

Comment: @bugfroggy Ooops I didn't set my question right ^^" I just want to delete the item concerned, but I noticed that my onClick method wasn't responding on my console (if I put a console.log just after:  ``` $('#delete_beerlist').on("click", function(){``` , nothing appears

Comment: please post generated html code.

Comment: @Juliette Are you adding the button to the page after the document is ready? The most likely scenario I can spot is you're registering the event listener and then adding the button afterwards. You must add the button first and then register the event listener.

Comment: @robere2 I'm generating the button with a .each, does that mean that it's added afterwards the document is ready?

Comment: @Juliette It could. It's hard to say without seeing your entire code. If you edit that part into your question then I can maybe provide more information.